# To find all odd integers $n>1$ such that $2n \choose r$ , where $1 \le r \le n$ , is odd only for $r=2$

Tags: reference-request, ring-theory, soft-question, binomial-coefficients

For which odd integers $n>1$ is it true that $2n \choose r$ where $1 \le r \le n$ is odd only for $r=2$ ? I know that $2n \choose 2$ is odd if $n$ is odd but I want to find those odd $n$ for which the only value of $r$ between $1$ and $n$ such that $2n \choose r$ is odd , is $2$ . I am wanting to know this as for such an $n$ , if $a^{2n}=a , \forall a \in R $ where $R$ is a ring then $R$ is commutative .Indeed $-a=(-a)^{2n}=a^{2n}=a$ so $2a=0 , \forall a \in R$ ; then since $a^2,a$ commute , so in the expansion of $(a^2+a)^{2n}$ , since $2n \choose r$ is even for all $r$ between $3$ and $2n-3$ , and also ${2n \choose 1 }={2n \choose 2n-1}=2n$ is even  , these terms vanish due to $2a=0 , \forall a \in R$ , so

$(a^2+a)^{2n}=(a^2)^{2n}+ {2n \choose 2}(a^2)^{2n-2}.a^2+{2n \choose 2n-2}(a^2)^2.a^{2n-2}+a^{2n}=a^2+ a^{4n-2}+a^{2n+2}+a=a^2+a^{2n-1}+a^3+a$

so $0=(a^2+a)^{2n}-(a^2+a)=a^{2n-1}+a^3=a^{2n-1}-a^3$ that is $a^{2n-1}=a^3 , \forall a \in R$ , so

$a^4=a.a^3=a.a^{2n-1}=a^{2n}=a , \forall a \in R$ , thus R is commutative ; so please help to find all odd

integers $n>1$ such that  $2n \choose r$ , where $1 \le r \le n$ , is odd only for $r=2$ . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

Let $2 n = n_{0} + n_{1} 2 + \dots + n_{k} 2^{k}$ be the base $2$ expansion of $2 n$, so all $n_{i} \in \{0, 1\}$. We have $n_{0} = 0$, $n_{1} = 1$, and may assume $n_{k} = 1$, that is, $2^{k-1} \le n < 2^{k}$.

Similarly, let $1 \le r = r_{0} + r_{1} 2 + \dots + r_{k-1} 2^{k-1} \le n$, with $n_{i} \in \{0, 1\}$.

Then by [Lucas' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem)
$$
\binom{2n}{r}
\equiv
\prod_{i=0}^{k} \binom{n_{i}}{r_{i}}
\equiv
\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \binom{n_{i}}{r_{i}}\pmod{2}.
$$
So the left hand side is even when there is an $i$ such that $n_{i} = 0$ and $r_{i} = 1$. You want this to happen for all $2 < r \le n$.

If there is $1 < i < k$ such that $n_{i} = 1$, then $r = 2^{i} \le 2^{k-1} \le n$, and
$$
\binom{2n}{r} \equiv 1 \pmod{2}.
$$

So the required condition is that for all $1 < i < k$ we have $n_{i} = 0$, that is, $2 n = 2 + 2^{k}$, that is, $n = 1 + 2^{k-1}$ for some $k > 1$.

Comment: A nice way to visualize this is by noting that if you take Pascal's triangle and then "paint" all odd numbers black and all even numbers white, you get an approximation of Sierpinski's triangle (this is [illustrated here](http://mathforum.org/workshops/usi/pascal/pascal_sierpinski.html), for instance). The even rows where the only black $1\leq r \leq n$ is $r=2$ are exactly the rows of the form $2n=2+2^k$.

Comment: Great comment, @Pierre-GuyPlamondon, thanks!

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: In the generating function proof of the Lucas' theorem , given in wikipedia , I cannot understand one thing , how does one equate   the co-efficients of like powers of $x$ ?? If it is meant to be a polynomial then I can see $1.x^2+1.x=x^2+x \equiv (\mod 2) , \forall x \in \mathbb Z$ but certainly $2$ does not divide $1$ , so they are off-course not talking about this , so then what are they considering when they equate co-efficients of like powers of $x$ ??

Comment: They are equalities between polynomials (as sequences of coefficients), not polynomial values.